# Regexp in Golang not matching

Tags: regex, go

I'm currently writing tests for SQL using the package [sqlmock](http://godoc.org/github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock), however, I've been unable to find a regular expression that seems to match what I would have thought was a relatively simple expression.

I've included a play url with the code below. However, I'm unsure as to why these strings don't match?

http://play.golang.org/p/I6QZkjkLmj

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var myExp = regexp.MustCompile(`SELECT count(\*) FROM video_resource WHERE key = $1`)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(myExp)
    fmt.Println("SELECT count(\\*) FROM video_resource WHERE key = $1")
    matched := myExp.MatchString("SELECT count(\\*) FROM video_resource WHERE key = $1")
    fmt.Println(matched)
    fmt.Printf("%+v", myExp.MatchString("SELECT count(*) FROM video_resource WHERE key = $1"))
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to match a substring or the entire string?

Comment: For others, I was trying to match the entire string. It's part of the sqlmock library as a method to do mock integrations for the database/sql library in golang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression contains [metacharacters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) that need to be escaped.

```
regexp.MustCompile(`SELECT count\(\*\) FROM video_resource WHERE key = \$1`)
```

<kbd>[**Play**](http://play.golang.org/p/byCW-Y7UTB)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I was intensely focused on the *, and totally oblivious to the other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Brackets and dollar signs are significant in regular expressions and should be escaped.

This would make your first boolean evaluate to true:

```
`SELECT count\(\\\*\) FROM video_resource WHERE key = \$1`
```

or this for the second:

```
`SELECT count\(\*\) FROM video_resource WHERE key = \$1`
```

See here: http://play.golang.org/p/apkker73wr